# Wine is not installing

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, wine

I tried to install Wine. I followed the all the things from Wine website. It showing some error. The error screenshot is attached below. I tried many things but none worked. I am using Kubuntu 18.04. Thanks in advance.
This is the error message I got.

```
karan@karan-asus:~$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
[sudo] password for karan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 3.0.2~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: And what happens if you try to install `wine-stable`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Type this command `sudo apt-get autoremove` , and then `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with wine not showing in the menu on 18.04 - But it will still install and can be run from a terminal. 
install from terminal with this command `sudo apt install wine-stable wine32` Then navigate to the folder where your .exe file is located and install the program with this command `wine setup.exe` exchanging setup.exe with the actually name of the file.

after that if you need to configure the install you can type `winecfg` and bring up the wine configuration tool.

I'm sure this will all get fixed eventually - until then you can use the terminal or perhaps install playonlinux for a nice gui.
Good Luck.

Comment: Now when i try to install, it shows wine is already installed. But when i tried to install windows software via terminal, it shows an error that wine is not found.

Comment: you have to cd to the folder that your windows program is in.  And you may have to use the the full path to the file also, something like /home/<your user name>/Dowloads/XXXXXX.exe  where XXXXXX.exe is the actual filename of the program.

Comment: Ofcourse I did that in a download folder where my windows program file is.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to install it was remove the hq from the command, sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-stable

It installed.